# delete files with numbered names in matlab directory

Tags: matlab, delete-file

I'm new to matlab and I've wrote a code that implements the gamma function for image processing. I generate around 300 photos named '001.jpg' to '300.jpg' and then use ffmpeg to make a video.
In the end, I only need the video result and need a command to delete all the photos generated in the directory! is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all `.jpg` files in the current directory you can use the [`delete`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html) command with a wildcard (`*`)

```
delete('*.jpg')
```

If the files live in a folder other than the current directory, you can specify the directory in this way.

```
folder = '/path/to/my/files';
delete(fullfile(folder, '*.jpg'))
```

If you want to limit it to *just* files that have number filenames, you could do something like the following

```
files = dir('*.jpg');
filenames = regexp({files.name}, '^[0-9]+\.jpg$', 'match', 'once');
filenames = cellstr(cat(1, filenames{:}));

delete(filenames{:})
```

Comment: the `delete('*.jpg')` would work just fine if there weren't other pictures in my folder! but the regex worked perfectly, thanks for that. could you explain what `'match'` and `'once'` do in the second line?

Comment: @AlalehA That just makes it so that if it matches, it returns the match (the filename) so that `filenames` is a cell array containing the filenames to remove

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Suever's answer (not allowed to comment yet):
Assuming you already know the names of the images you're creating, you could save your script a 'trip' to the folder and back by creating the filenames list yourself thus:

```
for i=1:numOfImages
filenames(i)={strcat(num2str(i),'.jpg')};
end

delete(filenames{:})
```